# How to force terminate Qthread and ThreadPoolExecutioner Threads

Tags: pyqt5, qthread, threadpoolexecutor

Iam working on a script using PYQT5 GUI to do network script using paramiko and iam using pyQT Qthread as below in my main application class i created below function to run a script which reads csv file get IPs and hostnames and then call another QObject Class:

```
class MemoryUtilizWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MemoryUtilizWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Logo.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle('Memory Utilization Script Options')
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def MemoryRunScript(self):
        InventoryFile = self.InventoryCombo.currentText()
        if InventoryFile:
            Routers_List = []
            Routers_Names = []

            line_count = 0    
            with open(path + '\\Script Data\\Inventory Database\\' + InventoryFile) as csv_file:
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                for row in csv_reader:
                    if line_count == 0:
                        pass
                    else: 
                        Routers_Names.append(row[1])
                        Routers_List.append(row[2])
                    line_count+=1
            Not_Accessible_Routers = open(path + "\\Script Data\\Routers Summary\\Not Accessible Routers.txt" , 'w+' , encoding='utf-8')  
            Login_Incorrect_Routers = open(path + "\\Script Data\\Routers Summary\\Login Routers Routers.txt" , 'w+' , encoding='utf-8')   
            TACACS_Down_Routers = open(path + "\\Script Data\\Routers Summary\\TACACS Down Routers.txt" , 'w+' , encoding='utf-8')         
            Wrong_Hostname_Routers = open(path + "\\Script Data\\Routers Summary\\Wrong Hostname Routers.txt" , 'w+' , encoding='utf-8')  
            Username = 'user'
            Password = 'pass'
            self.MemoryProgressBar.setMinimum(0)
            self.MemoryProgressBar.setMaximum(len(Routers_List))
            self.RunScriptButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.InventoryCombo.setEnabled(False)
            self.InventoryButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.InventorytLineEdit.setEnabled(False)

            self.MemoryThread = QtCore.QThread()
            self.MemoryObject = MemoryThreading(Routers_List,Routers_Names,Not_Accessible_Routers,Login_Incorrect_Routers,TACACS_Down_Routers,Wrong_Hostname_Routers,Username,Password)
            self.MemoryObject.moveToThread(self.MemoryThread)
            self.MemoryObject.Finished.connect(self.MemoryFinished)
            self.MemoryThread.started.connect(self.MemoryObject.MainThreading)
            self.MemoryThread.start()
            self.MemoryObject.Progressvalue.connect(self.ProgressValue)
```

---

the QObject class i used multithreading technique of ThreadPoolExecuter to run fast as the IPs are over 3000 IP which will take forever:

```
class MemoryThreading(QtCore.QObject):
    Finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    Progressvalue = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self,Routers_List, Routers_Names, Login_Incorrect_Routers,TACACS_Down_Routers,Not_Accessible_Routers,Wrong_Hostname_Routers, Username, Password):
        super().__init__()
        self.Routers_List = Routers_List
        self.Routers_Names = Routers_Names
        self.Login_Incorrect_Routers = Login_Incorrect_Routers
        self.TACACS_Down_Routers = TACACS_Down_Routers
        self.Not_Accessible_Routers = Not_Accessible_Routers
        self.Wrong_Hostname_Routers = Wrong_Hostname_Routers
        self.Username = Username
        self.Password = Password

    def MainThreading(self):
        i = 0
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as self.executor:
            self.results = self.executor.map(RouterConnection, self.Routers_List,self.Routers_Names,itertools.repeat(self.Login_Incorrect_Routers),itertools.repeat(self.TACACS_Down_Routers),itertools.repeat(self.Not_Accessible_Routers),itertools.repeat(self.Wrong_Hostname_Routers), itertools.repeat(self.Username), itertools.repeat(self.Password))
            for result in self.results:
                i+=1
                self.Progressvalue.emit(i)
                try:
                    if result:
                       print(result)

                except Exception as exc:
                    print(exc)

        self.Progressvalue.emit(0)
        self.Finished.emit()
```

my concern is how to force this Created threads during execution of the script to stop so that the user can run the script and also stop it if possible i searched and googled a lot but didn't find any solution to my case as iam using both QThread and ThreadpoolExecutor

Comment: Create a flag for the `MemoryThreading` object (like `self.keepRunning = True`) when the loop starts, and check it at every iteration of the loop; when you want to stop it from anywhere, set that flag (`self.MemoryObject.keepRunning = False`), so that the loop will exit. Btw, only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not variables or functions.

Comment: thank you very much , its very nice idea and it is working